# How to use elisp to create a sqlite specific shell?

Tags: sqlite, shell, emacs, elisp

I'm trying to learn how to use elisp to customize my development environment. I've included the following function to create the command `M-x ipython` which opens an IPython shell:

```
(defun ipython ()
  (interactive)
  (ansi-term "/usr/bin/ipython" "ipython"))
```

I'm using sqlite on a project, and I wanted to make it easier to open a sqlite command shell in emacs. This is similar to the above example, but has the catch that I need to specify a database file. If I modify the above as follows:

```
(defun sqlite3 (filename)
  (interactive "FDB file name: \n")
  (ansi-term "/usr/bin/sqlite3" "sqlite3")) ;; Oops, what do I do with the file name?
```

I'm stuck, because the `ansi-term` function only takes two arguments, one being the program to be run, and the other being the optional name to rename the shell.

Is there an easy way to create a function that would allow me to easily open a sqlite shell with opportunity to provide the file argument to be passed to sqlite?

Comment: Since you're already using IPython, you can use it as a SQL shell with ipython-sql: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ipython-sql.

Comment: @jpkotta It is interesting to know that `ipython-sql` exists, but it seems awkward as a replacement for the sqlite shell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
(defun sqlite3 (file)
  (interactive "fDB file name:\n")
  (term-send-string
   (ansi-term "bash" "sqlite3")
   (format "sqlite3 %s\n" file)))
```

Comment: The one thing this code doesn't do (that I desire) is rename the buffer to `sqlite3`. So I edited your answer.